# Fetching document snapshots from firestore and mapping to them to a dart object

Tags: flutter, dart

Been trying to fetch a list of documents from a nested collection in firestore using a streambuilder of type List. Upon calling the documents from the database service the length is called on null.Kindly Assist.

```
   //mapping firestore data to a dart object
     Trip.fromFirestore(Map<String, dynamic> doc)
  : title = doc['title'],
    tripId = doc['tripId'],
    budget = doc['budget'],
    tripType = doc['tripType'],
    location = doc['location'],
    timestamp = doc['timestamp'],
    tripDescription = doc['tripDescription'],
    tripDates = doc['tripDates'];

 //Database code:
Stream<List<Trip>> getUserTrips(String userID) {
return _db
    .collection('trips')
    .document(userID)
    .collection('usertrips')
    .snapshots()`enter code here`
    .map((query) => query.documents)
    .map((snapshot) => snapshot
    .map((document) => Trip.fromFirestore(document.data))
    .toList());
```

}

```
//Homepage:
SliverToBoxAdapter(
        child: StreamBuilder<List<Trip>>(
          stream: Database().getUserTrips(user.userId),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return Loader();
            }

            final trips = snapshot.data;

            return ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: trips.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                //print(snapshot.data[index].title);
                return Text(trips[index].title);
                //TripCard();
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      ),

//The Error:
 The getter 'length' was called on null.
 Receiver: null
 Tried calling: length
 The relevant error-causing widget was
 StreamBuilder<List<Trip>>
```

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be final, You're working with a stream, and streams change.

```
  final trips = snapshot.data;
```

The snapshot is of type List as far as i can see. The stream should look like this.

```
SliverToBoxAdapter(
        child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: _db
                    .collection('trips')
                    .document(userID)
                    .collection('usertrips')
                    .snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return Loader();
            }

            var trips = snapshot.data.documents; //edit

            return ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: trips.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                //print(snapshot.data[index].title);
                return Text(trips[index].title);
                //TripCard();
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what if i want to work with the database service as posted above where i can map the firestore documents to a dart object, how can i go about that?

Comment: You can do that, info will be saved in trips variable as it contains all the documents in the collection.

Comment: True, i have used that approach of mapping firestore docs to an object, but there seems to be an error which i cant locate, which concerns the length of the documents..kindly assist in locating the error.

Comment: Do you get the same error after the changes? Also, i edited my answer

Comment: Your approach works fine no errors, but am trying to figure out the error from my approach? if i use your approach the database service i created will not be used anywhere in the app.

Comment: The only thing i can suggest is to debug your getUserTrips(), it seems to do a whole lot and that can be error prone. Put prints in every map and see where it goes wrong. But from experience, I wouldn't recommend this approach. Parsing a stream like this will make your app slower to start, and you will have to add a bunch of error handling since there's a possibility that every mapping fails. Instead do the heavy work and filtering after you retrieved the stream.

Comment: Appreciate your advice, will have to look into that.Thanks.